# I want to form several Vector Array from a set of features and list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

Each individual dictionary represents one vector array.

```
A=['apple','dog','cat','donkey']
B=set(A)
print B: -> ['apple','dog','cat','donkey']

Vector_Dict=[{'apple':2},{'dog':3,'donkey':5},{'cat':7}]
```

I want the ouput to be:

```
$[2,0,0,0]
[0,3,0,5]
[0,0,7,0]
```

Comment: it's technically impossible as a `set` is unordered. btw, on stackoverflow, we need to see **YOUR OWN EFFORTS** (code, etc.) to solve the problem you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you do not use the set B or make it again a list, what you need is:

*for any dict in Vector_Dict, build a list where each element is the value or the corresponding key from list A, or 0 if the key is not present in the dict*.

Translated into Python it gives:

```
for d in Vector_Dict:
    l = [ d[k] if k in d else 0 for k in A ]
    print(l)
```